# what is the difference between policy and gate laravel

Tags: php, laravel

hi all I learned laravel policy and Gates but I don't know what the main difference between them

I try both policy and gates but I do not know what the main difference between them can anyone
could you help me in that?
is the main difference is that policy for one model but gate for multiple models??

Comment: A gate keeps someone out but a policy is like the instructions telling gate who is allowed and not allowed. Check this link for better understanding.  https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#:~:text=Laravel%20provides%20two%20primary%20ways,a%20particular%20model%20or%20resource.   https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/what-is-the-difference-between-gates-and-policies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Policies are more focused on fine-grained authorization checks tied to specific Eloquent models, while gates provide a more general way to define custom authorization logic that can be used throughout your application. The choice between using policies or gates depends on your specific authorization requirements and the level of granularity you need for your authorization checks.